# Word for mutually bemoaning a shared experience?

Tags: synonyms

I thought **commiserate** was the word I was looking for, but found out that means sympathy for someone else's experience, rather than two or more people mutually feeling sorry for themselves.

Comment: "share sorrow" comes up as a synonym

Comment: What exactly does “mutually bemoaning a shared experience” **mean**? It seems a very odd phrase, and I can’t figure out what you’re trying to say with it. You can’t mutually feel sorry for yourself, that doesn’t make any sense. You can mutually feel sorry for _each other_; is that what you mean? Can you give a practical, real-world example of two people doing this to illustrate?

Comment: Yes, I mean a group of people feeling sorry for each other (as well as themselves). In my case, it is a group of people working on a difficult project.

Comment: Regarding Commiserate: You may just be looking in to new/limited a dictionary. http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=commiserate&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search "We should commiserate our mutual ignorance. Locke." "Syn. -- To pity; compassionate; lament; condole."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commiserate will do just fine. If A sympathizes with B at the same time B sympathizes with A for the same reason, they **commiserate with each other**. And this has been going on for a while now.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commiserate+with+each+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommiserate%20with%20each%20other%3B%2Cc0
[image]

Of course, a rather less formal phrase would be **bitching and moaning**. Take your pick.